# How to recover the text of the sentence from an embedding (vec2text)?

Tags: embeddings

I'm trying to re-invent the code that would do it in the same way as in the vec2text article. Does anybody here have something similar?

Comment: please don't assume anything, cite articles, post code, and potentially explain extensively what you want to do

Comment: also, consider that the embedding is a latent space, where the token space instead is a one hot encoding, thus has no latent structure... the best you IMHO can do is train a decoder to learn a psudo inverse of such embedding matrix